# Hadoop Streaming with Python 3.5: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming, mapreduce

I'm trying to run my own mapper and reducer Python scripts using Hadoop Streaming on my cluster built on VMware Workstation VMs.

Hadoop version - 2.7, Python - 3.5, OS - CentOS 7.2 on all the VMs.

I have a separate machine which plays a role of a client application host and submits the mapreduce job to the resource manager. Map and reduce scripts are stored there as well.
I'm using the following hadoop command to run a job:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar -output result1 -input /user/hadoop/hr/profiles -file /home/hadoop/map.py -mapper map.py -file /home/hadoop/reduce.py -reducer reduce.py
```

I also tried to insert "python3" interpreter before -mapper and -reducer scripts:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar -output result1 -input /user/hadoop/hr/profiles -file /home/hadoop/map.py -mapper "python3.5 map.py" -file /home/hadoop/reduce.py -reducer "python3.5 reduce.py"
```

However, the job always fails and I'm still getting the same error messages in the log:

```
2016-10-07 21:57:10,485 INFO [IPC Server handler 1 on 41498] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1475888525921_0004_m_000001_0 is : 0.0
2016-10-07 21:57:10,520 FATAL [IPC Server handler 2 on 41498] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1475888525921_0004_m_000001_0 - exited : java.lang.RuntimeException: **PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127**
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

2016-10-07 21:57:10,520 INFO [IPC Server handler 2 on 41498] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1475888525921_0004_m_000001_0: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: **PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127**
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

2016-10-07 21:57:10,521 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1475888525921_0004_m_000001_0: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

2016-10-07 21:57:10,523 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1475888525921_0004_m_000001_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from RUNNING to FAIL_CONTAINER_CLEANUP
2016-10-07 21:57:10,523 INFO [ContainerLauncher #2] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: Processing the event EventType: CONTAINER_REMOTE_CLEANUP for container container_1475888525921_0004_01_000003 taskAttempt attempt_1475888525921_0004_m_000001_0
2016-10-07 21:57:10,524 INFO [ContainerLauncher #2] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: KILLING attempt_1475888525921_0004_m_000001_0
2016-10-07 21:57:10,524 INFO [ContainerLauncher #2] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : slave-1:56838
```

Python 3.5 interpreter is installed on all VMs across the cluster and its path is added to system's PATH as well. I can launch the interpreter on all nodes using **python3.5** command.

I tried to run the same command with the same scripts on my NameNode and it worked. So it seems like it's an HDFS security issue.

I've already read many posts related to this problem and tried everything what was suggested, but still no progress.

I've tried the following already:

- disabling dfs permissions
- redirecting stdout to sdterr in map and reduce scripts
- since I'm using VMs, I reduced RAM and CPU requirements for containers: 256MB and 1 core
- adding "python3" interpreter before -mapper and -reducer options in "hadoop jar" command
- I replaced CRLF with Unix LF in my scripts

All my scripts have **#!/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5** string pointing to interpreter's location. I've tested my scripts several times - they are working just fine.

I'm completely new to this topic and now I'm stuck. Please, if you know how to fix this, share your experience. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that when I was using python 3.5, Hadoop Streaming couldn't process input/output of scripts properly. So I had to migrate my app to python 2.7 and it's working now.